# String.valueOf() to return empty string instead of null

Tags: java

I have the below method call.
If `name` or `desc` is null, it uses the word null. Instead I would like an empty string.

How to achieve this as part of the method call itself. I don't want to do this outside of the method call with if conditions.

```
boolean creatok = users.create (String.valueOf(name), String.valueOf(desc));
```

Comment: Either use a library that supplies a default value, or write one yourself and use it instead.

Comment: I believe the only option without conditional checking is to use a ternary operator.

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean creatok = users.create (Objects.toString(name, ""), Objects.toString(desc, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use conditions, if you want to avoid 'if' clauses, use a ternary operator

```
boolean creatok = users.create(name == null? "" : String.valueOf(name), name == null? "" : String.valueOf(name));
```

Comment: boolean createok = users.create (String.valueOf(name) == null ? " " : String.valueOf(name), String.valueOf(desc) == null ? " " : String.valueOf(desc)) It still returned null. What am I doing wrong

Comment: null as String or null as reference ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you don't want to write if else

`boolean creatok = users.create (name == null ? "" : name, desc == null ? "" : desc);`